# Search DLNA(Upnp) media renderers for remoteplayback

Tags: android, android-emulator, upnp, dlna

I am trying to write a DLNA application using the Cling Java library. I Can able to search all the media servers  in the DLNA network and play the  content also. But i need to search Media Renderers available in the network and play the content on them. Just like [UPnPlay](https://market.android.com/details?id=cx.hoohol.silanoid&hl=en) does.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class MyUpnpService extends AndroidUpnpServiceImpl {

@Override
protected AndroidUpnpServiceConfiguration createConfiguration(WifiManager wifiManager) {
    return new AndroidUpnpServiceConfiguration(wifiManager) {

        @Override
        public ServiceType[] getExclusiveServiceTypes() {
            return new ServiceType[] {
                    new UDAServiceType("AVTransport")
            };
        }

    };
}
```

}

Searching for devices with "AVTransport service" capability solved the issue of searching for Media renderers for remote playback. For remote playback i found enough documnetation from [this](http://teleal.org/projects/cling/support/manual/cling-support-manual.html#javadoc.example.mediarenderer.AVTransportTest.testCustomPlayer..)